# curl POST work with user meta but not the custom user meta

Tags: api, rest-api

I created a custom user_meta, but I cant update it via curl.

I can do this with user_meta

```
curl --header "Authorization: Basic ACCESS_TOKEN" -X POST -d "description=New description" http://domain.com/wp-json/wp/v2/users/1
```

But I cant do the same with custom meta

```
curl --header "Authorization: Basic ACCESS_TOKEN" -X POST -d "user_continent=Asia" http://domain.com/wp-json/wp/v2/users/1
```

[image: JSON screenshot]

This may help

How I add the custom meta to the API:

```
add_action( 'rest_api_init', 'adding_user_meta_rest' );

function adding_user_meta_rest() {
$user_metas = array('account_psn_title', 'account_psn_id', 'account_steam_title', 'account_steam_id', 'account_twitch_title', 'account_twitch_id', 'account_xbox_title', 'account_xbox_id', 'account_youtube_title', 'account_youtube_id', '_uw_balance', 'user_continent', 'user_platform');
    foreach ($user_metas as $user_meta) {
        register_rest_field( 'user',
            $user_meta,
            array(
                'get_callback'      => 'user_meta_callback',
                'update_callback'   => 'user_meta_update_callback',
                'schema'            => null,
            )
        );
    }

}
function user_meta_callback( $user, $field_name, $request) {
    return get_user_meta( $user[ 'id' ], $field_name, true );
}
function user_meta_update_callback( $user, $field_name, $request) {
    update_user_meta( $user[ 'id' ], $field_name, XXXX );
}
```

function `user_meta_update_callback` is my attempt to make those custom meta editable.

What should I put in `user_meta_update_callback` in place of the XXXX?
Am I doing right?

Comment: is `user_continent` a meta you have coded yourself ?

Comment: Yes, it's. a custom user_meta.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

arguments `get_callback` and `update_callback` receive different arguments.

try this exemple which works for a field `user_continent`

```
add_action("rest_api_init", function () {


    register_rest_field(
          "user"
        , "user_continent"
        ,
        [
            "get_callback" => function ($user, $field_name, $request, $object_type) {

                return get_user_meta($user["id"], $field_name, TRUE);

            },
            "update_callback" => function ($value, $user, $field_name, $request, $object_type) {

                update_user_meta($user->ID, $field_name, $value);

            },
        ]
    );


});
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll get the value as the first parameter, or you could get it out of $request, which is a [WP_REST_Request](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_rest_request/) object. Since you're using `POST`, the parameters out of `$request->get_body_params()` which will return an array. If you just need the actual meta value, you don't need to do this.

Your callback function should look something like this:

```
function user_meta_update_callback( $value, $user, $field_name, $request ) {
    update_user_meta( $user[ 'id' ], $field_name, $value );
}
```

Comment: You are right. But only user id not work. The URL contains the user id at the end "http://any.com/wp-json/wp/v2/users/1"

Comment: I user `$request['id']` instead of `$user['id']` and it now work