# Is it possible to update a post meta field through REST API if the format of it when registered is nested?

Tags: post-meta, rest-api

I am able to get the custom REST API fields using meta key values to be formatted like this:

```
"location": {
    "lat": "000001",
    "long": "000002"
},
```

The works fine when I am trying to retrieve values of the post but when I am trying to add posts using REST API, the location fields doesn't seem to store anything, when I check my current code gives out an error.

Here is my update function:

```
    register_rest_field( $this->post_types, 'location', 
        array(
            'get_callback' => array( $this, 'get_location_meta' ), 
            'update_callback' => array( $this, 'update_location_meta' ), 
            'schema' => null
        )
    );

    public function get_location_meta($object, $field_name, $request) {
        return array(
        'lat'    => get_post_meta($object['id'], 'latitude', true),
        'long'   => get_post_meta($object['id'], 'longitude', true),
    );
}

    public function update_location_post_meta($value, $object, $field_name)
        return array(
            'lat'    => update_post_meta($object->ID, 'latitude', true),
            'long'   => update_post_meta($object->ID, 'longitude', true),
        );
    }
```

The custom field key names in Wordpress are latitude and longitude.

But now I am not sure what will be the field name I will target to be able to fill in some values for the latitude and longitude metakeys. When I try to send a value to `location` using Postman, I am getting an unexpected error.

Thanks in advance for any suggestion.

Comment: the update callback is not called with the same arguments as the get callback : https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/293025/curl-post-work-with-user-meta-but-not-the-custom-user-meta/293089#293089